# Conditionally include service in angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS. I have

```
app.service('list', function () { .. get $('#list') .. });
app.service('grid', function () { .. get $('#grid') .. });

app.controller('myController',['$a', 'list', 'grid', function ($a, list, grid) { 
    if ($scope.isList)... list 
    if ($scope.isGrid)... grid
}]);
```

When my `$scope.isList` I don't need the "`grid`" service (because is undefined)

*I understand that this could be done in an other way, using separate controllers, etc etc...*

But my **main** question is: **Is it possible to conditionally include dependent services?**

Say by eg:

```
app.controller('myController',['$a', function ($a) { 
    if ($scope.isList)... thisController.AddDependency('list', list);
    if ($scope.isGrid)... thisController.AddDependency('grid', grid);
}]);
```

Comment: Nope, but you can use $inject and do the check in the controler